# Planned private posts get published immediately

Tags: posts, private

Somehow, it doesn't seem to be possible to plan post for my subscibers (visibility private) as they get published private automatically as soon as I save them.

Is there any way I can keep wordpress from doing so?

Comment: Deactivate all plugins, switch to the default theme. Does it still happen?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately, this did not do the trick :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that changing the post **visibility** to private invokes a **status** change, in a way private is not only a visibility but also a publishing status. Or to quote the **Wordpress Codex**, section »[Content Visibility - Private Content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Visibility#Private_Content)«.

> Once you change the visibility to private, the post or page status
>   changes to "Privately Published" as shown. Private posts are
>   automatically published (...).

To achieve what you want you probably have to work with the [publish_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post) or even better the [publish_future_post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/121181/22534) hook. Another possibility is to work with [Post Status Transitions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) and the according hooks.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to answer my question. So as far as I understand, I might have to code? I was hoping there as an easier way ;)

Comment: Not that I know of, but if you find one, come back an d share it. I recently wrote an answer about making a [custom post type private by default](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/118976/22534), of course this isn't exactly what your are looking for, but maybe it'll help you out getting there anyway.

Comment: If i find a Solution of course.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked your timezone settings under Settings -> General? One of the things that can cause this is if the schedule date is in the past according to the configured timezone but not  according to your time.

Comment: Are you really, really sure about that?