# Can not get future_to_publish to work

Tags: post-status

I'm trying to figure out why `future_to_publish` will not work. Here is a list of what I have checked to work:

1. `draft_to_publish`
2. `future_post`
3. `publish_post`
4. `transition_post_status` (works draft to future, but not future to publish)

I can't seem to figure out the problem. I'll include the test code I'm using below:

```
function on_post_scheduled( $ID, $post ) {
    $fp = fopen( get_template_directory() . "/files/foo.php", 'r+' );   
    if ( flock( $fp, LOCK_EX ) ) {
        ftruncate( $fp, 0 );      
        fwrite( $fp, "future post published" . mt_rand( 0, 255 ) );
        fflush( $fp );           
        flock( $fp, LOCK_UN );
    }
}
add_action( 'future_to_publish', 'on_post_scheduled', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'new_to_publish', 'on_post_scheduled', 10, 2);
add_action( 'draft_to_publish', 'on_post_scheduled', 10, 2);
```

Comment: there is the `publish_future_post` action hook, which gets triggered when posts are transitioned from »future« to »publish«, see my [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/121181/22534) for a little bit more information

Comment: `publish_future_post` does not work either.

Comment: You need to get more descriptive, does not work, really does not help anybody. You might have to do some in depth debugging and come back with it.

Comment: So after some testing, the cron job for `publish_future_post` is being set and executing. For some reason the function is not activating. 
I even tried doing `wp_schedule_single_event`. In that case it still created the cron job, but it never executed the action i created (which was tied to the function I'm trying to execute). I even activated debug mode and added a print to that at each step. No errors and it only printed when the post is scheduled.

Comment: I had the same problem and it was not working because I had the "add_action( 'publish_future_post'..." call wrapped inside of "if ( is_admin() ) {"

Comment: @TorreLasley BINGO! I also had it wrapped in `is_admin()`, while triggering cron (`/wp-cron.php`) outside admin permission.